# keyboard shortcut for viewing/applying available refactorings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, coderush-xpress

I just installed CodeRush Express and was wondering is there any keyboard shortcut for viewing/applying available refactorings. Currently I have to click on the small underline/underscore to get the available refactorings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general shortcut for that dropdown in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>  (control + full stop).
Works for VS even when CodeRush is not installed.

Also for CodeRush is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> (Control + apostrophe) which will either show the refactoring list (without having to wait for the underscore to appear), or apply the refactoring if there is only one available.

EDIT: The shortcut for CodeRush is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> for UK keyboards, but (I think) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> for US keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, which will bring up the options dialog for CodeRush Express, where you can find the keyboard shortcuts.

If I'm not mistaken, the CR Express shortcut for refactoring defaults to the backtick key on english keyboards.

Personally I have bound it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.